# ImageView looks disgusting after orientation change

Tags: android, imageview

When I change the screen orientation from portrait to landscape it turns really ugly. What can be done to prevent this. I need the quality of image to be set proerly?

Comment: Can you share your layout xml, screenshots, and more info on what you are expecting to see?

Comment: @Ujwal Shrestha Share screenshot.

Comment: you can create separate layout for landscape mode.